# What is a quieter alternative to gas forced air heating?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace

My small 1BR apartment has an old gas furnace that works great, but costs my landlord too much to insure. He plans to install gas forced air, an in-unit upright furnace. I'd love to suggest a comparably priced alternative that will make less noise. What's out there?

edit: Maybe a few self-contained baseboard heaters and\or [quartz infrared](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4633/13014) heaters could do the trick, for a small enough place? Mine is only about 700 sq ft. A similar unit in the building got a [Rheem Criterion II](http://www.rheem.com/documents/rgph-specification-sheets) gas furnace, so (@HerrBag) I'm afraid 90% may be overly optimistic.

Comment: you might mosey by the local Rheem dealer and mention your concerns.  That model does have a multi speed blower.  It might be inquired whether the max speed can be limited during installation.  That model also has a constant fan setting, that is usually very slow and quiet.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe my neighbor's is malfunctioning, or maybe these things belong in larger apartments and out-of-the-way closets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-stage burners are much quieter at low burn, as are multi speed/variable speed blower motors.  These features are available for most 90% and higher furnaces.

A nice co-generation water heater (hot water for heat and a super storage unit for potable hot water) would be very quiet, but conversions costs to add radiators would not likely fly.